# How to check if message starts with regularexpression

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and am now trying to optimise it. I dont want to have many "or"s in my if statement, and someone suggested I use regularexpressions.
this is my attempt

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(/\**(this)/)) {
        message.channel.send('***... ground control to major Tom***');
    }
```

I am trying to reply to messages that start with "this is", or the italic, bold or both versions.

I used to have:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('this is') || message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('*this is') || message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('**this is') || message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('***this is')) {
        message.channel.send('***... ground control to major Tom***');
}
```

Can I check if the message contains using the regularexpressions?

Thank you

Comment: "*realexpression*" Can you clarify if you're actually referring to a [*Regular* Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: Could you add the whole previous if condition?

Comment: @esqew yes i did. thank you for point that out.

Comment: @KeshavramKuduwa, here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const content = message.content;
const regex = /^this is|^\*{1,3}this is/gmi;

if (regex.test(content)) {
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked.
If that isnt too much could you please explain what the expression means, because as you saw the one i made from google asearches is very different. (like what parts do what)
Thank you!

Comment: Sure but first I'd suggest take a look at [the basic RegEx rules](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and if you did not figure out then you could ask me to explain and update the post